# Angular 2 view not updating after model change

Tags: angular

Can't get my view to update even though my model clearly is updated. Tried using NgZone but it doesn't help.

I'm injecting RouteService in two components: app.component and start-page-list.component.
RoutService is using Subject to pass data between components:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Round } from "app/round";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

@Injectable()
export class RoundService {

  private roundSource = new Subject<Round>();

  roundItem$ = this.roundSource.asObservable();

  changeRound(value:Round) {
    this.roundSource.next(value);
  }
}
```

app.components view gets updated as expected but start-page-list.component does not.

app.component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { RoundService } from "app/round.service";
import { Round } from "app/round";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>{{currentRound.id}}</h1>
  </div>  
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class AppComponent {
  currentRound: Round = {id:0,name:"No round set yet"};

  constructor(private http: Http, private round : RoundService) { }

  callBackFunc(data:Round) {
    this.currentRound = data;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.round.roundItem$.subscribe(
      (data:Round) => this.callBackFunc(data)
    );
  }  
}
```

Here currentRound.id is updated!

start-page-list.component (rendered at the router-outlet in app.component):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { PlayerService } from "app/player.service";
import { Game } from "app/game";
import { Player } from "app/player";
import { GameService } from "app/game.service";
import { RoundService } from "app/round.service";
import { Round } from "app/round";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-start-page-list',
  template: `{{currentGameset.id}}`,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class StartPageListComponent implements OnInit {

  currentGameset:Round = {id:0,name:'No round set yet'};

  constructor(private gameService: GameService, private roundService: RoundService, private zone: NgZone) { }

  callbackFunc(data:Round) {
    this.currentGameset = data;
    console.log("currentGameset.id= " + this.currentGameset.id);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.roundService.roundItem$.subscribe(
      (data:Round) => this.zone.run( () => this.callbackFunc(data) )
    );
  }  

}
```

Here currentGameset.id is not updated even though  the model is (console log shows updated value). As you can see I've tried using NgZone.

Any suggestions what might be wrong here?

**Edit**
If i put the start-page-list.component as a child component to the app.component i don't get the problem. Then the view gets updated as I expect. The problem seems to be only when I use the router-outlet rendering of the component.

Comment: Where do you call `changeRound`?

Comment: In another component also rendered by the router-outlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that using BehaviorSubject instead of Subject in the service was the solution!

Anyone care to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `currentGameset = data`, you're breaking what the template was referring to. You would think that it will continue to refer to the currentGameset but that's not how it works!

Try to add a wrapper for currentGameset like:

```
gameSetParent = { 
  currentGameset: {id:0,name:'No round set yet'};
}
```

In callback func,

```
this.gameSetParent.currentGameset = data;
```

You need to update the template to reflect the change.

Comment: That don't explain why it works for the currentRound in the app.component.html. I tried your suggestion by the way and I didn't have any luck with it.